# Python streaming from webcam through an ML process to the internet

Tags: python, video-streaming

I am trying to develop a program in Python that streams a webcam captured video, through an ML process, to "the internet".

Are there particular packages for Python that are designed to handle the live webcam capture and streaming/receiving from the internet?  The ML processes I understand fairly well but currently require loading from storage whereas I'm trying to understand essentially how to make a P2P video chat client in Python.

Any pointer are greatly appreciated

Comment: use `opencv`. Here's their documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html

Comment: if you means webcam which has own URL then `opencv` can read it directly. Here is example with webcams in Poland - [python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer).

Comment: If you means webcam in user's computer which visits your web pages then `web browser` needs `JavaScript` to send stream to server, next server can use your code to process image, and next `web browser` needs `JavaScript to receive image/stream and display it - example [web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server)

Comment: Thank you @MusabbirArrafi .... It looks like the answer to my question is in the [VideoCapture()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) 

I can stream frames from a webcam to my other script leveraging this.  I'll do some more digging in the OpenCV API but I'm wondering once I have the modified frames how best to reassemble them into a video stream that can be captured by other processes.

Comment: well I can provide you with a basic-template for video capture and then send them over to other client devices. Look into my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture video from webcam using the `opencv-python` like the following:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Open the default camera (0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read a frame from the webcam

    # Perform your ML processing here on 'frame'

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)  # Display the frame

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' to exit
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For streaming video over a network, you can use `imagezmq` library for streaming OpenCV images from one computer to another. It's based on ZeroMQ, a messaging library that allows you to connect multiple devices over a network.

#### for sender device:

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")  # Set the appropriate address and port

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Perform your ML processing here on 'frame'

    _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    socket.send(jpg_as_text)

cap.release()
```

#### for receiver device:

```
import zmq
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://sender_ip:5555")  # Replace 'sender_ip' with the actual sender's IP

socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

while True:
    jpg_as_text = socket.recv()
    jpg_original = base64.b64decode(jpg_as_text)
    jpg_as_np = np.frombuffer(jpg_original, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(jpg_as_np, flags=1)

    cv2.imshow('Receiver', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' to exit
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is a basic approach for video streaming setup using `OpenCV` for webcam capture, ML processing on frames, and `imagezmq` for streaming frames over a network. But do keep in mind that setting up a P2P video chat client involves more complexities, such as handling network discovery, establishing connections, handling latency, and potentially incorporating signaling protocols. For a full-fledged P2P video chat, you might consider additional libraries or frameworks specifically designed for real-time communication, like WebRTC.
You can get a more clear idea from this tutorial I found: https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/04/15/live-video-streaming-over-network-with-opencv-and-imagezmq/

Comment: Thank you Musabbir, I'm not sure how to mark this as the correct answer but you definitely knocked a few hours off my learning curve.  I appreciate it.